# Maintaining state of variables when changed inside a timer

Tags: javascript, variables, timer

I am using JavaScript.

I amusing a setInterval timer method.

Inside that method I am changing the values of module variables.

The thing is in IE the changes to the variables are not 'saved'. But in Chrome they are.

What is the accepted practice to do what I need to do?

this is my code:

```
function start()
{
    var myVar = setInterval(function () { GetTimings() }, 100);
}

var currentts1;
var currentts2;
var currentts3;
var currentts4;
var frameCounter;


function GetTimings() {
    if (frameCounter < 1) {
        frameCounter++;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", urlTS, false);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                var nextts = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var bits = nextts.split('|');
                if (currentts1 != bits[0]) {
                    currentts1 = bits[0];
                    postMessage("0|" + bits[0]);
                }
                if (currentts2 != bits[1]) {
                    currentts2 = bits[1];
                    postMessage("1|" + bits[1]);
                }
                if (currentts3 != bits[2]) {
                    currentts3 = bits[2];
                    postMessage("2|" + bits[2]);
                }
                if (currentts4 != bits[3]) {
                    currentts4 = bits[3];
                    postMessage("3|" + bits[3]);
                }
                frameCounter--;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The variables:

1. currentts1
2. currentts2
3. currentts3
4. currentts4
5. frameCounter

values are not preserved...

Comment: So from looking through this, you want to _DoS attack_ the server when when the request takes longer than 100ms?

Comment: the intent is to determine whether the server has an update for my client. If so then download the image.

Comment: Also, if you just `var frameCounter;` without setting it, `frameCounter < 1; // false` and `frameCounter++; // NaN`

Comment: the 'frameCounter' is used to allow only 1 request at a time.  I was just fiddling with the interval value. It can be 1000ms or more if need be..

Comment: HI, good point. Missed it in my copy + paste

Comment: so, is there a reason why state is not managed between calls? Especially for IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but notice I changed the `currentts*` to an *Array* when you try to view them

```
function start() {
    var myVar = setInterval(GetTimings, 100);
}

var currentts = [null, null, null, null];
var in_progress = 0; // clear name

function GetTimings() {
    var xhr;
    if (in_progress > 0) return; // die
    ++in_progress;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', urlTS);
    function ready() {
        var nextts = this.responseText,
            bits = nextts.split('|'),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < currentts.length; ++i)
            if (currentts[i] !== bits[i])
                currentts[i] = bits[i], postMessage(i + '|' + bits[i]);
        --in_progress;
    }
    if ('onload' in xhr) // modern browser
        xhr.addEventListener('load', ready);
    else                 // ancient browser
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
                ready.call(this);
        };
    // listen for error, too?
    // begin request
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Hi,This did not work for me. IE still has a problem with it.  The only additional info I have is that I am using this code within a web worker.  But, i had tried my code outside the web worker (I am using IE9) and it did not work either. I will now try this code outside the web worker and get back. But your code was a vast improvement on mine so many thanks

Comment: Im not sure what is going wrong, exactly. Do you get any messages in your console?

Comment: Good morning, I have taken another look at this.  It failed for 2 reasons.  Firstly, I was calling this on a timer whose interval was set at '10'. I changed that to '100'.  I also changed the 'GET' to a 'POST'. Then it all worked. Weird as I have only found this to be for the case in IE.

Comment: Will give you the 'tick; because it got me to the solution so thanks :